# rails and prototype question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

I am trying to use afterfinish callback to set focus on a text field after a prototype's Effect and I am not getting this javascript right.

Can someone help me?

```
<%= link_to_function "Enter Data" do |page |
      page.visual_effect :appear , 'section1', 
          :afterFinish => "document.getElementById('name').focus()"
    end %>

<div id="section1" style="display:none;">
         <%= label_tag 'Your Name' %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'name', '', :size => 20 %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me

```
page.visual_effect :appear, 'section1', :afterFinish => "function(){$('name').focus()}"
```

This is a limitation of rjs wherein you cannot insert prototype methods like Jordan suggests, Instead you have to put raw js.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Prototype method [`focus()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/element/focus) you should do it like this:

```
<%= link_to_function "Enter Data" do |page |
      page.visual_effect :appear , 'section1', 
          :afterFinish => "Form.Element.focus('name')"
    end %>
```

Comment: thanks! but I get this error
 this.options[eventName] is not a function

Any idea why? Appreciate your help

Comment: State the value of afterFinish as follows:
afterFinish: callToYourFunction

and not:
afterFinish: callToYourFunction()